# MBPOLL error when adding -t 4:float option

Tags: raspberry-pi, modbus

I can use mbpoll to poll my modbus temperature and depth sensor using

```
mbpoll -m RTU  -t 4 -a 1 -b 19200 -r 45 -c 16 /dev/ttyUSB1
```

however when I try to display the data as a float in order to make it legible I get an error. I attempt this using the code

```
mbpoll -m RTU  -t 4:FLOAT -a 1 -b 19200 -r 45 -c 16 /dev/ttyUSB1
```

Right now the data is displayed as a figure such as `16824` but It should read something like `22.4` (being degrees C). Using Modbus Poll on my PC I am able to do this by selecting the cell and choosing to display it is a `FLOAT AB CD`, so I assumed (probably incorrectly) that this was what I was supposed to do in MBPOLL.

Thanks!

Comment: "I get an error" - what error? (when posting a question please include all relevant info). Note that `-t 4:FLOAT` takes two 16 bit registers to output a 32 bit float (this may mean that the `-c 16` is causing the issue; reduce the number of values requested). I believe you will also need `-B` (Big Endian) but that would not cause an error (just an unexpected result).

Comment: Sorry- it has been a long time since I’ve used this forum and I’m still getting back up to speed with the etiquette. Thank for you your comment- this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the answer in the comments in case someone finds this in the future:

When using `modpoll` with floating point numbers (e.g. `-t 4:FLOAT`) two 16 bit registers will be combined to output each 32 bit floating point value. This may mean that `modpoll` is requesting more registers (32) than expected. The result may be an error if non-existent registers, at the end of the range, are being requested (I'd expect exception 2 - `ILLEGAL DATA ADDRESS`). This can be resolved by reducing the number of values requested.

I believe you will also need -B (Big Endian) but that would not cause an error (just an unexpected result).